# The angle at which a circle and a hyperbola intersect?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> $x^2 - 2y^2 = 4$
>   $ (x-3)^2 + y^2 = 25 $

How do you calculate the angle at which a circle and a hyperbola intersect?

If I express $y^2$ from the first equation and apply it to the second equation, I get the following:

$y^2 = -2 + \frac{x^2}{2}$
$(x-3)^2 + -2 + \frac{x^2}{2} = 25$ ... $x^2 - 4x - 12 = 0$
$x_1 = 6, x_2 = -2 \implies y_1 = 4, y_{1'} = -4, y_2 = 0$

Now, for the points $(6,4)$ I could calculate the line equation which intersects the circle and the hyperbola: $(6-3)(x-3) + (4-0)(y-0) = 25 \implies y = -\frac{3x}{4} + \frac{17}{2}$

I calculated this because I thought I could apply the formula $\tan\phi = |\frac{k_2 - k_1}{1 + k_1k_2}|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$(1):$ From the article $151$ of [The elements of coordinate geometry (Loney)](http://archive.org/details/elementsofcoordi00lone),  the gradient $(m_1)$ of $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ is $=-\frac{x_1+g}{y_1+f}$ where $(x_1,y_1)$ is the given point on the circle

and from the Article $305,262$  the gradient $(m_2)$ of $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is $\frac{b^2\cdot x_2}{a^2\cdot y_2}$ where $(x_2,y_2)$ is the given point on the hyperbola

$(2):$ Alternatively, find the gradients of each curve at $(6,4)$ and at $(-2,0)$ applying first order derivative

The [acute angle](http://planetmath.org/anglebetweentwolines) between the curves will be $$\arctan\left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2} \right|$$

Comment: So, for the point $(6,4)$ (one of the three points where the circle and the hyperbola intersect) it would go like this: $m_1 = -\frac{6+(-3)}{4 + 0}$, the hyperbola equation: $\frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{y^2}{2} = 1$ and $m_2 = \frac{2 * 6}{4 * 4} = \frac{3}{4}$ and $\tan\phi = \frac{\frac{3}{4} - (-\frac{3}{4})}{1 - (\frac{3}{4}*(-\frac{3}{4})}) = \frac{24}{25}$ Is this correct?

Comment: @Shirohige, have you followed the approach? If the method is right, so the answer should be.

Comment: Yes I have, I've written the equations in the above mentioned forms and used the corresponding coefficients in the formulas and applied them to the same point where the hyperbola and circle intercept. That should be OK then.